# Storage Migrations on Rococo?

Tags: storage, rococo, migration

GM everyone, has anyone noticed storage migrations stopped running on rococo?

We are on 0.9.43 and can not get migrations to run, both through the pallets or the runtime

running trace logs doesn't indicate any issue so I was wondering if anyone faced something similar

The same migrations ran fine on Kusama though so I do wonder if its a rococo specific issue or we are doing something wrong

We are in the process of wiring up `try-runtime` to try and get to the bottom of it and once we have logs ill post them here

Answer (score 2):

it was spec version, we have `94301` saved on rococo and then upgraded to 09432 a few weeks ago.

but all our further upgrades are still less than 94301. so we had to kill the `lastRuntimeUpgrade` under the `system` pallet first then do the upgrade again and that kicked off the migrations